# Designing a Crossword Grid for iOS in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, gridview, uicollectionview

I've developed a crossword app for android and managed to create the grid using the `GridView` class provided in the android support library and buttons ([This one](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)).

I've tried to use UICollectionView with a custom layout but it seems  to be designed for other purposes. Does anyone know what can I use to create the same (or a similar) thing in iOS?

Is there a library that makes easier to crate a fixed table like this one?

Note: the number of columns and rows is fixed **10x10**

I'd prefer to use Swift over Obj-C and i'm not caring about the keyboard and the menu yet.

Thank you very much

I attach a screenshot of the android app.

Sorry for my english, it is still bad :)

[image: Android View]

Comment: UICollectionView is the perfect thing for your requirement. Where did you get stuck with UICollectionView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIViewController should work fine for your needs. Try something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

   var collectionView: UICollectionView!
   var gridSize: CGFloat = 10

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
       layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
       layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1

       collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0), collectionViewLayout: layout)
       collectionView.dataSource = self
       collectionView.delegate = self
       collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

       collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       view.addSubview(collectionView)

       view.addConstraints([
           NSLayoutConstraint(item: collectionView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
           NSLayoutConstraint(item: collectionView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
           NSLayoutConstraint(item: collectionView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20),
           NSLayoutConstraint(item: collectionView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: view.frame.width) ])

   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
   }

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return Int(pow(Double(gridSize), 2))
   }

   func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
       return 1
   }

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
       // Set up your cells here
       return cell
   }

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
       let size = view.frame.width / gridSize - 1
       return CGSize(width: size, height: size)
   }

}
```

Setting the `backgroundColor` of your cells will give you this:

[image]